# Java SSL OCSP checks fail to validate the entire chain of trust with Certificate does not specify OCSP responder

Tags: java, ssl, ocsp

I have a Java application that recently moved to SSL and it has a problem when performing checks on all certificates in the chain of trust, but works fine when I set it to check the server certification only.

Checks are performed using OCSP only (cannot do CRL here).

So, if I'm setting in Java Control Panel the **'Perform TLS certification checks on' - 'All certificates in the chain of trust'** , java application is saying that certification is untrusted with the following error message:

```
com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException: 
Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
```

In the same time, if I change to **'Perform TLS certification checks on' - 'Server certificate only'**  everything works fine, hence the certificate is valid.

My certificate has this chain: rootCA - intermediateCA - server

I checked the Authority Information Access value for all the 3 certificates and it looks that the root one does't have one set and implicitly it doesn't have an OCSP url where to check the validity, however I checked other certificates and looks like most of the rootCA doesn't have it.

Any idea what can be the problem or how I can continue to debug it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the rootCA in your Trusted catrust store of Java ?

Comment: Yes, I have. The problem seems to appear because the rootCA and the intermmediateCA are not providing an OCSP url where java can check the authority.